# How to use managed resources with scala-arm

Tags: scala, resource-management

How can I use `scala-arm` in the code here below so that `inputStream` is released automatically?

```
def inflate(data: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
  val inputStream = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), new Inflater)
  Stream.continually(inputStream.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
}
```

I've tried something like this... but of course the last statement fails because method `toArray` is not a member of  `resource.ExtractableManagedResource`:

```
def inflate(data: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
  val outputStream = for {
    inputStream <- managed(new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), new Inflater))
  } yield Stream.continually(inputStream.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte)

  outputStream.toArray
}
```

Here is a working example of how I use `scala-arm`to manage an output stream:

```
def deflate(data: Array[Byte]) = {
  val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  for (deflaterOutputStream <- managed(new DeflaterOutputStream(outputStream, new Deflater))) {
    deflaterOutputStream.write(data)
  }

  outputStream.toByteArray
}
```

Is there a more concise, scala-oriented way to deal with managed resources and `scala-arm` (or `scalax.io`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using [scalax.io](https://github.com/jesseeichar/scala-io) as an alternative to scala-arm to return a `Traversable[Byte]` which will lazily read from the stream

```
def inflate(data: Array[Byte]): Traversable[Byte] = {
  val inflater = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), new Inflater)
  Resource.fromInputStream(inflater).bytes
}
```

or you can convert this `Traversable[Byte]` into an `Array[Byte]` which will read the entire `InputStream` into memory:

```
def inflate(data: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
  val inflater = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), new Inflater)
  Resource.fromInputStream(inflater).bytes.toArray
}
```

Here's how you might use the `Deflater`:

```
def deflate(data: Array[Byte]) = {
  val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  Resource.fromOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(outputStream, new Deflater)).write(data)
  outputStream.toByteArray
}
```

Comment: Wow fantistic. But what if I want to use scalax.io also to write into a stream - see the deflate example I added to my post.